# Rolling correlation in pandas returning NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, matching, rolling-computation

I would like to get the best match of a small array "b" (length: few hundreds of elements) from a bigger array "a" (length: few millions of elements).
I am trying to use pandas, rolling and corr for comparing "b" with a sliding window over "a".
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
    
a = pd.read_csv(<file1>) 
b = pd.read_csv(<file2>)
    
normalized_a = (a - a.mean()) / a.std() 
normalized_b = (b - b.mean()) / b.std()

res = a.rolling(window=len(b)).corr(b)
```

Dataframe a is:

```
                 0
0        0.941042
1        0.656281
2        0.969081
3        0.881595
4        0.848359
...           ...
1814386 -1.323574
1814387 -1.351035
1814388 -1.359450
1814389 -1.296941
1814390 -1.266813
```

Dataframe b:

```
0   -2.256496
1   -2.949674
2   -1.614618
3   -1.784006
4   -0.976331
..        ...
287  0.378578
288  0.247859
289  0.375981
290  0.444575
291  0.450435
```

However, res contains all NaNs, but one element (in fact, output of res.count() is 1):

```
          0
0       NaN
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4       NaN
...      ..
1814386 NaN
1814387 NaN
1814388 NaN
1814389 NaN
1814390 NaN
```

The only non-NaN element in res is located at row 291 (found with res.idxmax()):

```
280       NaN
281       NaN
282       NaN
283       NaN
284       NaN
285       NaN
286       NaN
287       NaN
288       NaN
289       NaN
290       NaN
291 -0.134144
292       NaN
293       NaN
294       NaN
295       NaN
296       NaN
297       NaN
298       NaN
299       NaN
```

Does anybody know why I get all these NaNs? I would have expected to get meaningful values after row 292. Is corr a pairwise operation?

Thanks!

Comment: It's still using the index for alignment so since `b` has an index from 0 - 291 the corr will always try to match that. So nothing is going to match for the later rows.

Comment: You are trying to find the best match of a short array `b` with a longer array `a`. You don't need a rolling correlation to do that. You simply need a normal cross-correlation. This will already slide array `b` along the axis of array `a`. Check out `numpy.correlate` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html

Comment: thanks for your answers! Unfortunately, numpy.correlate is very slow (length of a is almost 2 millions). I tried also scipy.signal.correlate, but strangely the best match it returns is way far from the ground truth. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @gisk Yes, for long arrays you should use `scipy.correlate`, since it supports the FFT-method which is way faster. I forgot to mention that. As for determining the best match, please show us what you have tried so far (with code snippets).